# How to autostart Linux novnc with x11vnc

Tags: vnc, x11-forwarding, novnc

I was trying to use my old computer as a remote desktop.
I installed Ubuntu 22 and wanted to connect to it via browser.
I can somehow make it work via those 3 commands, but when I put them in an start.sh file it doesn't work the same.

These are the commands:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/novnc.pem -out /etc/ssl/novnc.pem -days 9999
x11vnc -storepasswd VNCPASS /tmp/vncpass

xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num 44 --auth-file /tmp/xvfb.auth -s "-ac -screen 0 1920x1080x16" xfce4-session
x11vnc -rfbport 4544 -rfbauth /tmp/vncpass -display :44 -forever -auth /tmp/xvfb.auth
websockify -D --web=/usr/share/novnc/ --cert=/etc/ssl/novnc.pem 6080 localhost:4544
```

I tried using nohup but it still isn't working. Which is the right way to make them work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to docker and built my own vnc image based on kasmweb...
Will be using the container instead of the pc wich has extra advantages btw.
For persistency I mapped the volumes. In my case, this aproach works...yet not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo vi /etc/init/x11vnc.conf


# description "Start x11vnc on system boot"

description "x11vnc"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

console log

respawn
respawn limit 20 5

exec /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/silvia/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
```

Comment: Hi, doesnt seem to work

Comment: okay i am sorry if this code not helping